# Bucket sort:Why don't we set range to 1? vs counting sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, counting, bucket

Bucket sort creates k buckets....and distribute n numbers in one of those buckets..
Eg.1-10, 
11-20,
21-30...
O(n+k)

The no.s within the bucket are sorted using insertion O(n²)

It works fine when few numbers end up in same bucket.. O(n+k)
But if all numbers end up in same bucket ...O(n²)

My question is if we make range of buckets as 1 ie 0-1
,1-2,
2-3.....
Different no.s won't end up in same bucket....(no sorting within bucket required)
O(n+k)

Without concerning space complexity why don't we use this instead of counting sort?
Plzz correct me if I m wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you propose is a distribution sort called *count sort*, only a simpler version where you know that elements are not duplicated, so counting stops at `1`.  It is very efficient in time `O(N+n)` but does require `O(N)` space.

Many people will naturally use this method when asked to sort a deck of cards: they will dispatch each card to its position on the table in order to form 4 lines of 13 cards. The final step is to gather the cards line by line. Here we have `N == n` and since both steps take `O(n)` time, the sort is very efficient.

When `N` becomes substantially larger than `n`, say you want to sort a pile of 20 dollar bills by the order of their serial numbers, this method becomes totally impractical.

If you are sorting integers, you might consider another method with `O(n)` time complexity: Radix sort.

Comment: Can u plzz provide me any reference to direct sort?(just to explore more:-) ).....couldn't find when I googled...

Answer (score 0):

The value of k is not the same in the first approach and the one you propose. Assume you have n numbers between 0 and N. In the first case (buckets of size ten) you need N/10 bucket, in the second case (buckets of size one) N buckets. Depending on the relative values of N and n, there will be an optimal for k which may not be k=1.